# Simple HTML DOM missing data

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Hello I am working on a project where I am trying to pull data off of a webpage. I am running into an issue where certain items aren't being pulled.

```
    <?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.websiteform.com/forum/items');


   echo $html;
    ?>
```

I noticed when I go to the page on a forum link I get a mouse tip displaying the body of the first post. I would like to pull this info. I looked at the html and i see its being displayed in title. IE:

```
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_877485" title="This is the body of the actual first post">
```

but with the above code is doesn't come across when dumping the variable $html IE:

```
<td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_877485" title="">
```

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Is the content perhaps loaded through ajax?

Comment: Very well could be.. I am not sure how to test this?

Comment: If you have the console open when you reload the page, you will see right away.

Comment: what would I be looking for?

Comment: Server requests being made.

Comment: I am not seeing anything like this... any other place to look?

Comment: look for that string in the response or subsequent responses. Look in your chrome network tab for ajax calls but it's more likely in the original response. Try phantomjs if none of that makes sense to you.